# Set memory timing manually to decrease row hammer effect on DDR3

Tags: memory

My system is vulnerable to row hammer during memtest86 test, I've read there's a way to fix this without change hardware:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer#Mitigation

> A less effective solution is to introduce more frequent memory refreshing, with the refresh intervals shorter than the usual 64 ms, but this technique results in higher power consumption and increased processing overhead.

I looked into my Gigabyte-Z77X-ud3h BIOS, there's tons of memory timing settings, but no one is currently at "64", could anyone tell me which setting should I change?

Comment: "On March 9, 2015, Google's Project Zero revealed two working privilege escalation exploits based on the row hammer effect." - Why would you want to fix it? and why now?

Comment: @RamonRobben Why not?

Comment: I don't think I'll broke the RAM just by refresh it faster, and I can withstand the slower speed for security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia states that the "Usual" refresh interval is 64ms this means that this is not the refresh rate for everyone. If you are above this number of refresh interval just lower it below 64ms. But there are some problems that might occur.

The setting you are looking for is the "DRAM Refresh interval" setting.

> A less effective solution is to introduce more frequent memory
>   refreshing, with the refresh intervals shorter than the usual 64
>   ms,[a] but this technique results in higher power consumption and
>   increased processing overhead

Since the Ivy bridge connection from Intel they already lowered the timing intervals

> Since the release of Ivy Bridge microarchitecture, Intel Xeon
>   processors support the so-called pseudo target row refresh (pTRR) that
>   can be used in combination with pTRR-compliant DDR3 dual in-line
>   memory modules (DIMMs) to mitigate the row hammer effect by
>   automatically refreshing possible victim rows, with no negative
>   impacts on performance or power consumption. When used with DIMMs that
>   are not pTRR-compliant, these Xeon processors by default fall back on
>   performing DRAM refreshes at twice the usual frequency, which results
>   in slightly higher memory access latency and may reduce the memory
>   bandwidth by up to 2–4%.

The low refresh rate would mean that the ram will already refresh on lower intervals. Also they automatically refreshing possible victim rows which will also reduce the chances of getting exploited by this exploit.

I'm sure that you are more then safe from this exploit and that it will be very unlikely that you will get exploited trough this.

Comment: "Since the Ivy bridge connection from Intel they already lowered the timing intervals" Seems they didn't implement this on consumer CPUs, only XEON is mentioned.